# How to make javafx.scene.Scene resize while maintaining an aspect ratio?

Tags: javafx

I'm writing an application with JavaFX 2.2.7-b01.

Here is an example of the code I currently have. How can I allow the application window to be resized but maintain the aspect ratio it is initially configured with? In other words, if the user resizes the window, the window width should always stay double the window height.

```
  ...
  public void showScene(Stage stage, String fxmlPath) {
    try {
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
      loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
      loader.setLocation(fxmlPath);
      Parent page;
      try (InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream(fxmlPath)) {
        page = (Parent) loader.load(in);
      }
      Scene scene = new Scene(page, 400, 200);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.sizeToScene();
      stage.show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ...
    }
  }
  ...
```

It seems JavaFX allows a user to specify the width and height of a scene in the constructor but does not allow programmatic access to update the width or height. There are no setWidth or setHeight methods. I know I can add property listeners to get the *read only* width/height of the scene while it is being resized, but I haven't been able to figure out how to change the scene dimensions dynamically so I can force the aspect ratio to be maintained.

I imagine this would be possible if I were to subclass the Scene object (if I have to I will) but is there any other simple way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you will find a decent solution for this with JavaFX 2.2.  I advise logging a feature request against the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**>** `How to make javafx.scene.Scene resize while maintaining an aspect ratio?`

By manipulating the stage size instead of scene:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Play by resizing the window");
    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gray");

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.minWidthProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().multiply(2));
    primaryStage.minHeightProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().divide(2));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to point out that this solution is not perfect, as if you enlarge the window and then try to shrink it, it won't let you go all the way diagonally, you end up having to shimmy it from the bottom and from the sides.

Comment: at https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.javafx/blob/master/src/test/java/com/bitplan/javafx/stackoverflow/StageSize.java you'll find this example together with other resize related stackoverflow code examples

Comment: You can avoid the shimmying issue noted by MikaelF by binding both the min and max of one dimension to the other dimension e.g.

  stage.setMinHeight(580);
  DoubleBinding w = stage.heightProperty().subtract(28).divide(2);
  stage.minWidthProperty().bind(w);
  stage.maxWidthProperty().bind(w);
Note that you can then only resize the window in one dimension, with the other sizing automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use removeListener and addListener when changing value ​​to prevent listeners from chaining.

```java
private ChangeListener<? super Number> widthChangeListener;
private ChangeListener<? super Number> heightChangeListener;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    widthChangeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        stage.heightProperty().removeListener(heightChangeListener);
        stage.setHeight(newValue.doubleValue() / 2.0);
        stage.heightProperty().addListener(heightChangeListener);
    };
    heightChangeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        stage.widthProperty().removeListener(widthChangeListener);
        stage.setWidth(newValue.doubleValue() * 2.0);
        stage.widthProperty().addListener(widthChangeListener);
    };

    stage.widthProperty().addListener(widthChangeListener);
    stage.heightProperty().addListener(heightChangeListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans using Java Fx Scene Builder provide you can use AnchorPane Constraints to set 
Resizing of stage.