# JavaFx resize Window and preserve aspect ratio

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

currently I'm developing a JavaFX application and I want to resize the Window. 
Everytime I resize the Window, it snaps back to the initial size.

Globals.java

```
public class Globals {
  public static Stage primaryStage;
  public static int drawFactor;
  public static int initWidth = 800;
  public static int initHeight = 600;
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
          Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/MainWindow.fxml"));
          Scene rootScene = new Scene(root, Globals.initWidth, Globals.initHeight);
          primaryStage.setScene(rootScene);
          primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Application");
          primaryStage.show();
          Globals.primaryStage = primaryStage;
  } 
}
```

Controller.java

```
public class Controller {
@FXML
private StackPane pane;
@FXML
private Canvas canvas;

  /**
  * Method is called at start of the app, because it is in the FXML controller
  */
  public void initialize() {
      canvas.widthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
      canvas.heightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());
      canvas.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
              Globals.drawFactor = (double) newValue / Globals.initWidth;
              pane.resize((double) newvalue, Globals.initHeight * Globals.drawFactor);
              if(Globals.primaryStage != null) {
                Globals.primaryStage.getScene().getWindow().setHeight(Globals.initHeight * Globals.drawFactor);
              }
          }
      });
  }
}
```

MainWindow.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<StackPane fx:id="pane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60"
       xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
       fx:controller="Controller">
    <Canvas fx:id="canvas"/>
</StackPane>
```

If I resize the Window and the CanvasWidth Changelistener triggers, the Window Size changes, but in the end the WindowHeight snaps back to the initial Values (In this example to 600). The width accept the new value.

Is there a way to fix this problem or to resize the window and preserve the aspect ratio?

Comment: `initHeight * factor` > factor is not defined. Did you mean `drawFactor `?

Comment: Oh Sorry. Yes I mean drawFactor. I will edit my question

Comment: Please post [mcve]. It is not clear to me where is `canvas` initialized ? How do you invoke `initialize()`?

Comment: the initialized() methode is called when the FXML is loaded and `primaryStage.show()` is called. In the FXML the canvas is initialized

Comment: You mean that `initialize()` is in the controller ?

Comment: Yes. The `initialize()` method is in the Controller, that is declared in the FXML

Comment: Is this explained in your post ?

Comment: It's in the code. But i added a comment so everyone can see it immediatly

Comment: Please post [mcve] to eliminate all these questions (and many more, like how is `primaryStage` initialized in the controller ?  why aren't `StackPane pane` and `Canvas canvas` in the controller ? and more). This is only wasting the time of people trying to help, as well as your time.

Comment: To simplify this Post i put it al in one class. I edited my Code and everything is now in the right class and place.

Comment: please check here the solution...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18638505/7504001

Comment: _"If I resize the Window"_ Do you you mean manually resize ? If so the code provided does not demonstrate the problem. It doesn't snap.

Comment: If i resize the width of the window with my mouse: the Width and the height is changing. If I release the mousebutton the height jumps back to its initial size, the width stays at the new size.